# Upload image with Photoshop scripting

Tags: rest, scripting, plugins, photoshop

Is that possible to upload an image from Photoshop (for example, an open image exported to jpeg) to some web place - REST service, FTP etc by using scripting features of Photoshop? For example - I have an image open in Photoshop and then execute some special script that sends an exported version of it to some place over the  web. I saw something like this but it uses an automatically generated batch file that executes ftp command on Windows. I would like to use something more beautiful if it's possible. Or may be there are some info to know how to make a simple plugin for just this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The Photoshop API exposes a socket object. You can use it like this

```
function sendDataToServer(data) {

    var socket = new Socket(),
        port = 80,
        domain = "www.example.com",
        page = "/path/to/file.php",
        bin;

    if(socket.open(domain + ":" + port,"binary")) {
        socket.write("GET http://" + domain + page + "?data=" + data + " HTTP/1.0\n\n"); 
        bin = socket.read(9999999);
        alert(bin);
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

This will return the servers response plus the headers for the request. You can read the file through using a method like this:

```
function getLine(html){
    var line = "", i = 0;
    for (; html.charCodeAt(i) != 10; i++){ // finding line end
        line += html[i] ;
    }
    return line;
}
```

Also this method will strip the headers using the `getLine` method:

```
function removeHeaders(binary){
    var bContinue = true, // flag for finding end of header
        line = "",
        nFirst = 0,
        count = 0;

    while (bContinue) {
        line = getLine(binary) ; // each header line
        bContinue = line.length >= 2 ; // blank header == end of header
        nFirst = line.length + 1 ;
        binary = binary.substr(nFirst) ;
    }

    return binary;
}
```

Comment: I found it on a forum somewhere, there were a lot of scripting examples and shared code.

The forums are the place to look. It's been a long time since I've done any of this.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to upload files to REST web service is:
1. Use POST with Content-Type: application/octet-stream including the image stream in the body.
2. Use the "SLUG" header when POSTing to supply the image file name.

I don't know what kind of API PhotoShop exposes, but I guess there is an API to read the image stream, So using this API you can prepare the required POST request and adding the image to your server :-)

Hope that I helped,
Shay

Answer (score 0):

The API's within photoshop do not allow for network access.  They just control photoshop and are limited to user actions you can do within Photoshop.

I would suggest using Automator or another external scripting language to post-process the output of photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

If the Photoshop API doesn't support network access, you could try loading a Flash/Flex file from the script, and do then do the upload in the swf.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with JavaScript in photoshop:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/bridge/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide_cs3.pdf